# Selenium Looping and iteratively checking boxes

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

On this website https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1 I must create a big loop that will iteratively check the years boxes, after navigating through the entire website.

```
count = 0

listofyears = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="radio"]')

listofyears = webD.find_elements_by_css_selector("#input li")

lengthyears = len(listofyears)

                                         
for i in range(lengthyears):
     elem.click()
```

And then continue navigation. this doesn't work. How can I loop around checking boxes with selenium iteratively?

Answer (score 0):

A small demo of clicking the 7 years this will allow you do use driver.back() if you so chose to.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1")
listofyears=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-repeat='year in years']/label/input")))
print(len(listofyears))
for i in range(1,len(listofyears)+1):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[{}]/label/input".format(str(i))))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Import

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```